# Is it valid to have an 84-2-1 representation for the decimal 13 considering that we are dealing with 4-bits?

Tags: logic, converters

I want to create a table containing decimal values and its 84-2-1 code counterpart. I'm not sure if it is valid to convert a decimal number greater than 9 to 84-2-1 code because all materials that I have seen online only covers conversion to 84-2-1 from 0 to 9 only. I hope you can answer my question. Thanks!

[image: This is the conversion that I came up with.]

If values above 9 are not allowed to be converted into 84-2-1 code, may I know the reason behind this? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why the value of 12 should not be "allowed" as `1100` amounts to decimal 12 (8 + 4).
The values from 13 to 15 can not be represented by any 84-2-1-code because no combination of weights results in a value > 12.
Combinations with values > 9 are normally not used because the purpose of this code is, to represent single decimal digits. Hence there is no need for values greater nine.

Comment: So if I use 84-2-1 code in a counter, should my state table only contain decimal numbers from 0 to 9?

Comment: @Harvsvsvsv it depends on what you want to do. If your program interprets the codes as single digits there is no need (and no possibility) to use other codes then these for values from 0 - 9.  If you want to interpret the codes as states which are not digits: You can do that of course. But why would you use an 84-2-1-code in such a case?

Comment: it is a review for my upcoming test.